# Android's VideoView remembers bad links and won't play them for a while

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a very strange issue with android's VideoView class.

My app streams a video file from my server. Sometimes the app tries to fetch the video file before it is actually there (still processing), and I get error ( 1 , -1004) from the videoView's mediaPlayer. Than I try to stream the same url after the video is already in that path, but the videoView will keep sending the same error again and again for a few minutes.

Other clients (android/ios/vlc) will succeed playing that same video file, while the app that tried to play it while it wasn't in there will continue to fail for a few minutes.

The VideoView will succeed playing all video's 99% of time - the ony issue I have with it is this one.

1. I tried creating a new videoView instance to play that url, but it gives the same error -1004 (MEDIA_ERROR_IO).
2. I tried quitting the app / restarting the device - but that same url will continue to fail for a few minutes.
3. I tried copying the url from the failing device, to the VLC app in that device, and will succeed playing it.
4. The issue is not device/version specific - It happens to all the devices I tested on, and all android versions I tried:

   - Samsung galaxy s3 Jelly bean.
   - LG nexus 4 - kitkat.
   - Samsung galaxy nexus ICS.
   - Samsung Galaxy s2 gingerbread.
   - Samsung nexus s - ICS.

It's as if MediaPlayer is remembering that bad link, and will continue to send the same error for a while without checking it again.

Does the videoView cache links in any way?
What could be the issue??